# How to save SQL values from queries into variables?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Greetings guys and gals,

I've only started programming in ASP.NET and VB.NET recently, so I've been playing around with syntax and logic. Anyway, I have an SQL query which gets the details of the user based on the username that was inputted. My question is: since I SELECT * from a DB table, how do I place those values into a variable? The values that I would like to save to variables would be ID, Firstname, and Lastname. My plan is to save the current user ID who is logged in so it would show all across my application.

Here's what I have:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim strconn As New SqlConnection

    If strconn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        strconn.ConnectionString = ("Server=0.0.0.0;Database=Test;Uid=test;Pwd=test;")
    End If


    '//prompt user for blank user credentials
    If txtUsername.Text.Length = 0 Then
        Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">  alert('You must enter your Access Credentials.');</script>")

        'If MsgBox("You must enter your Access Credentials.", vbInformation, vbOKCancel) Then
        'End If
        txtUsername.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Try
        strconn.Open()
        Dim sQuery As String = "SELECT * from tblUsers WHERE username = '" & txtUsername.Text & "'" &
                               " AND password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'" &
                               " AND status ='" & "1" & "'"

        Dim datareader As SqlDataReader
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim parameter As New SqlParameter
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sQuery, strconn)
        command.Connection = strconn
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        datareader = command.ExecuteReader()

        If datareader.HasRows Then
            datareader.Read()
            'MsgBox("Login Successfull!     ", vbInformation, vbOKOnly)
            'Response.Redirect("http://localhost:0000/SecurityStaffDataEntry.aspx")
            Response.Redirect("http://localhost:0000/index.aspx")
            datareader.Close()
            LoginOk = True

        Else
            Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=""JavaScript"">  alert('Invalid Username or Password!');</script>")
            ' MsgBox("Invalid Username or Password!    ", vbInformation, vbOKOnly)
            txtUsername.Text = ""
            txtPassword.Text = ""
            txtUsername.Focus()
        End If
        datareader.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Thanks for that link marc_s. Moving forward with what was discussed in the link, how would my SELECT statement look like then? Like this perhaps: ' "SELECT * from tblUsers WHERE username = '" & @txtUsername.Text & "'" &'

Comment: It should be something like: `SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE username = @userName .....`  and then you set the value of the `@userName` parameter to that `txtUsername.Text` separately - not directly when creating the SQL statement

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but how would I go about to setting the value of @Username parameter to txtUsername.Text?

Comment: Brian: please read [this excellent article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx) on how to do this - too long for a simple comment :-)

Comment: Thank you for that article @marc_s. I've tried what was discussed in the article and it's working fine. And the code looks neat and clean too

Answer (score 0):

Put this after reader.Read() and replace textbox with variable

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    TextBox1.Text = reader[0].ToString();
}
```

You can also use

```
reader["columnname"].ToString()
```

Comment: If there is more than one record retrieved then value in the text box will be overwritten on each iteration.

Comment: In no case you can enter multiple records in single variable so you have to define your requirement more clearly about what you really trying to do.If you still wanna use single variable than concatenate values in variable and then pass that to textbox after loop ends.

Comment: And as per code of your questions you are doing something with username and password so as username is unique so it will always return single record...So u can actually use same method as in my code

Comment: It looks silly to use a while loop to overwrite values. If your don't expect more than one record then don't use a loop.

Comment: "In no case you can enter multiple records in single variable" `Dim dt As DataTable`. A `DataTable` can hold all the records in a single variable. Also a` List(Of T)` or a `Dictionary`.